# Create linear regression by chunks

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

Generate 25 points of the function `sin (x) + 2;` by means of

```
xS = linspace (0.2 * pi, 25); 
yS = sin (xS) + 2;
```

Find the lines that adjust the previous curve in intervals such that the error in each interval is less than 5%. Plot them next to the points.
[image]

Can anybody help me with this program?

my program:

linear regression function:

```
function [m,b,error, yApp]=f_regresionLineal(x,y)
xp = mean(x);
yp = mean(y);
n = length(x);
m = ( sum(x.y) -nxpyp )/( sum(x.^2)-nxp^2 );
b = yp-m*xp;
yApp = m*x+b;
error = mean(abs(y-yApp)./y);
end
```

script:

```
S = linspace(0,2*pi,25);
yS = sin(xS)+2;
plot(xS,yS,'r*')
grid on
axis tight
hold on

xxS=xS(1:8);
yyS=yS(1:8);
[m,b,error, yApp]=f_regresionLineal(xxS,yyS)
hold on;
plot(xxS,yApp,'b');

xxS=xS(8:18);
yyS=yS(8:18);
[m,b,error, yApp]=f_regresionLineal(xxS,yyS)
hold on;
plot(xxS,yApp,'g');

xxS=xS(18:22);
yyS=yS(18:22);
[m,b,error, yApp]=f_regresionLineal(xxS,yyS)
hold on;
plot(xxS,yApp,'k');

xxS=xS(22:25);
yyS=yS(22:25);
[m,b,error, yApp]=f_regresionLineal(xxS,yyS)
hold on;
plot(xxS,yApp,'y');
```

Comment: You really don't need to do `hold on` so often. Once is enough, it'll stick until you do `hold off`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I must say that there are so many typos in your code....

Second, in my viewpoint, [Piecewise linear regression](https://www.google.com/search?ei=6SvhWvXMFIiB8gX1h5zoCQ&q=piecewise%20linear%20regression&oq=Piecewise%20linear%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0i203k1l10.11777.14733.0.17700.12.11.0.0.0.0.272.1775.0j2j6.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..9.3.700...0i30k1.0.Zz6D5HU9JsI) is the method that fits your need(sorry but I'm not sure about the right name of this method in English).

Some calculation:
[image]

So we chose to fit a linear function to every three points.

Third, the code below are some extensions of yours:

f_regresionLineal.m

```
function [m,b,error, yApp]=f_regresionLineal(x,y)

xp = mean(x); yp = mean(y); n = length(x);

m = (sum(x.*y)-n*xp*yp)/(sum(x.^2)-n*(xp^2)); 

b = yp-m*xp;

yApp = m*x+b; error = mean(abs(y-yApp)./y);

end
```

script:

```
clc; clear;
xS = linspace(0,2*pi,25)'; yS = sin(xS)+2;

plot(xS,yS,'r*'); 
grid on 
axis tight 
hold on

L=1:2:length(xS);
for ii=2:length(L)
  xxS=xS(L(ii-1):L(ii));
  yyS=yS(L(ii-1):L(ii));
  [m,b,error, yApp]=f_regresionLineal(xxS,yyS);
  plot(xxS,yApp,'b');
end
```

Output:
[image]